# can't change the date with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need get data from website: https://www.eex.com/en/market-data/natural-gas/spot
But Changing the date in my script not working

I need get data from every available date, so i need change the date with Selenium
PLS Help. I'm new in Python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
from selenium_stealth import stealth
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url ="https://www.eex.com/en/market-data/natural-gas/spot"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver1/chromedriver", options=chrome_options)

browser.get("https://www.eex.com/en/market-data/natural-gas/spot")
time.sleep(10)
date_picker = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="symbolheader_ngs"]/div/div/div/input')))
date_picker.send_keys("2023-01-23")
time.sleep(20)

page_source = browser.page_source
s = bs(page_source)

table = s.select('table')[1]

final_list = []
for row in table.select('tr'):
   final_list.append([x.text for x in row.find_all(['td', 'th'])])
final_df = pd.DataFrame(final_list[2:], columns = final_list[:1])
final_df.columns = ['Spot', 'Last Price', 'Last Volume', 'End of Day Index', 'Volume Exchange','del']
df=final_df.drop('del',axis=1)

browser.quit()

df.to_excel('final_df.xlsx', index = False)
```

Comment: "But Changing the date in my script not working" What exactly does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear the input -> enter date -> push enter. You also want to wait for the clickability not the visibility of the element. Lastly you need to pick a date that has actual data.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


date_picker = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, """//*[@id="symbolheader_ngs"]//*/input"""))
)
date_picker.clear()
date_picker.send_keys("2023-01-20")
date_picker.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

If you comment out chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") you will see.

Comment: Great work. Ideally this solution should work +1